# How to log time of session destroying by php

Tags: php, session, logging, session-timeout

I have set the session destroy timeout to 25 minutes in `php.ini` file.
Is there a way to get and log the time of each session destroying? I want to save session destroying time in database somehow or send it by a GET request.
I should mention that if user send a request in 25 minute, session timeout will be renew.

Comment: You can insert the time of the session_start and predict the estimated time to removal.

Comment: You can also store a time in a $_SESSION var, like $_SESSION['creadted'] = time(), and make a script to detect if it exceeded 25 minutes and then log it to the db.

Comment: I want to log exact time of session removing. I mean when gc removes session. I'll update question to better understanding.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? What useful information do you hope to get from this?

Comment: I have no idea what is this for and what benefit it may have. It's just a force from a governmental organization on me and I really need it. I asked this question in multiple way in many websites but nothing till now.

Comment: PHP’s default GC mechanism doesn’t tell you when it discards a certain session. Either you need to implement your own session mechanism where you have complete control over that, or at least implement your own session GC and disable PHP’s own mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I have a custom session mechanism but php GC mechanism is also enable. I'll disable that to see what happens.